# VTP trunking not working for Cisco 4948 switch

Tags: cisco, vlan, ios

I'm adding a new Cisco 4948 switch to an existing network that has a bunch of 3500 series switches already configured and working.  I've verified the VTP domain and password are identical, tried pushing out a vlan change, but it is being ignored by the new switch.  Is there anything additional I need to do to get this working?  I've compared the config from one of the existing client switches and everything appears to be identical.
**Edit** Extra diagnostics:  on both primary and new switch, the port status is "FastEthernet1/0/39 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) " **End Edit**

On the PRIMARY switch, I have:

```
c3821.09#sh version
Cisco IOS Software, C3750 Software (C3750-IPBASEK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

c3821.09#show fa1/0/39
interface FastEthernet1/0/39
 description ##--network to/from switch09-02 79.14##
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
c3821.09#show vtp status
VTP Version capable             : 1 to 3
VTP version running             : 2
VTP Domain Name                 : abx
VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
Device ID                       : 001b.d468.1e80
Configuration last modified by 216.47.90.1 at 5-24-15 15:39:45
Local updater ID is 216.47.90.1 on interface Vl2 (lowest numbered VLAN interface found)

Feature VLAN:
--------------
VTP Operating Mode                : Server
Maximum VLANs supported locally   : 1005
Number of existing VLANs          : 54
Configuration Revision            : 12
MD5 digest                        : 0xED 0x80 0x46 0xDE 0xDF 0xBD 0xA8 0xC9 
                                    0x92 0x27 0x21 0xF1 0x8F 0x00 0x25 0x96
```

on the NEW switch (after resetting to factory defaults and only adding these configs) I have:

```
Switch#sh version
Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch Software (cat4500-IPBASE-M), Version 12.2(31)SGA4,
 RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

interface GigabitEthernet1/48
 description ## uplink to .9 ##
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!

Switch#sh vtp status
VTP Version                     : running VTP2
Configuration Revision          : 0
Maximum VLANs supported locally : 1005
Number of existing VLANs        : 35
VTP Operating Mode              : Client
VTP Domain Name                 : abx
VTP Pruning Mode                : Enabled
VTP V2 Mode                     : Enabled
VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
MD5 digest                      : 0xD3 0x7E 0x3B 0x1C 0x35 0x3E 0x32 0x8E
Configuration last modified by 0.0.0.0 at 5-24-15 16:01:20
```

Results from "sh cdp neighbor" - Primary.  This shows the 3 other switches in trunk mode, and one switch that simply acting as a switch

```
c3821.09#sh cdp neighbor
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone, 
                  D - Remote, C - CVTA, M - Two-port Mac Relay 

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
cloud-san        Fas 1/0/31        174              S I   WS-C4948  Gig 1/1
c3548.12         Fas 1/0/47        134              T S   WS-C3548- Fas 0/48
c3548.10         Fas 1/0/37        151              T S   WS-C3548- Fas 0/48
c3548.11         Fas 1/0/46        129              T S   WS-C3548- Fas 0/48
c3825            Gig 1/0/4         131             R S I  3825      Gig 2/0
```

New switch

```
cloud-wan#sh cdp neighbor
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater, P - Phone

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
```

Comment: `1.` is the VTP password correct on the new switch? `2.` What's the Configuration Revision number on the new switch? Also, see here - http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/vtp/98155-tshoot-vlan.html#topic8

Comment: @joeqwerty, he already stated he verified the password is correct on both switches and the coding revision is clearly indicated as 0.

Comment: John, you state that you are connecting the 4948 to 3500s, but your VTP server is running a 3750 image. Is this really a 3750 or a 3500 as indicated in your post?

Comment: Should be moved to: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YLearn - the primary switch is a 3750.  Sorry for the confusion - the other "client" switches were 3500s.  The 3750 is a 48-port switch module in my 3800 series router

Comment: @JohnP, can you add the output from *sh cup neighbor*? Since you mentioned the one interface is down, need to check if you have a link between the two.

Comment: @YLearn: Yes. thank you. I didn't catch that.

Comment: @YLearn: added output of "sh cdp neighbor"

Comment: Looks like you may not have an active link connecting the two.

Comment: @YLearn - is a crossover cable necessary? - I just am using a straight-through cable now.  I was fairly sure that both switches supported auto-discovery but I might have been wrong.

Comment: @JohnP, it shouldn't be. I don't recall for the 4948, but the 3750 does have auto-MDIX and only one side needs it. Did you try a different cable and different ports on each switch? You could also try entering *switchport* on each interface to ensure it isn't operating as a L3 interface.

Comment: @YLearn - different cables did not help.  On each server, the port was set to switchport.  The 4948 does work fine as a dumb switch (I can set a VLAN on a port on the primary switch, plug it into a random port on the 4948 and see traffic on it).